# Devices are registered with token in Apple Push Notification but don't receive notifications from the server

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

In my app, I have the following process for APNs:

- Register the device in *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*;
- Receive the token with *didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken*;
- Send it to my Notification server;
- My server sends the notification;
- **PROBLEM:** My device don't receive it (*didReceiveRemoteNotification* never called on Debug);

Already checked the App Id on the server and certificate.

Anyone can point what am I doing wrong?

---

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Checking if app is running iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]) {
        // Register device for iOS8
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings
                settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        // Register device for iOS7
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
    }

    //...

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"Registration successful, bundle identifier: %@, device token: %@",
            [NSBundle.mainBundle bundleIdentifier], deviceToken);

    // Receive the token and send it to my Server
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    // Handle notification
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Sandbox APNS server ? For debug mode you need to use the Sandbox APNS and certificate

Comment: [this link](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher) can help you.

Comment: You need to check the environment of your app and as per the environment you need to configure you push notifications, for development you have to create per file with development certificate and need to use in sandbox mode, while in production you have to use production certificate for per without sandboxing.

Answer (score 0):

[Lefteris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312312/lefteris) and [Rajat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4210332/rajat) are right, my problem was the wrong certificate for the enviroment.